# Melhor forma de distribuir programa que usa uma shared library

Tags: c, c++, c++11

Escrevi um programa que usa uma biblioteca chamada [curlpp](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp). O programa é bem simples e tudo que ele faz é fazer um requisição HTTP que retorna um JSON (uso a curlpp para realizar essa requisição), parsear esse JSON (uso a [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons) para isso) e imprimir na tela um dos valores dele. O programa tem apenas um arquivo de 50 linhas. Estou desenvolvendo no Linux Mint e compilo com o seguinte comando:

```
g++ -o wrapper main.cpp -lcurl -lcurlpp -std=c++11
```

O executável gerado funciona normalmente em meu computador, no entanto quando tento executa-lo em outros computadores ele diz que a biblioteca compartilhada curlpp não foi encontrada. Eu sei como funciona e quais são as diferenças entre bibliotecas compartilhadas e estáticas, mas minha pergunta é:

Tenho que obrigar meu usuário a instalar a curlpp antes de executar meu programa? Posso/devo distribuir a curlpp junto com meu programa? Existe alguma forma de "juntar" esse biblioteca ao meu programa em tempo de compilação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa distribuir a biblioteca junto com sua aplicação. Não precisa necessariamente instalar nada, apenas a biblioteca deve estar junto com sua aplicação, não importa a forma como você vai fazer isto. Pode ser uma simples cópia.

Pelo que li na documentação dela, a licença permite que você a distribua livremente sem restrições.

Aparentemente ela possui dependências. Então as bibliotecas também precisam estar junto da sua aplicação. A licença da [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) também não tem restrição que impeça a distribuição.

É possível *linkar* a biblioteca estaticamente, aí os binários dela serão incorporados ao executável da sua aplicação evitando dependências externas. Para isto ao invés de utilizar a biblioteca compartilhada, você precisa usar a biblioteca pura.

Precisa dar uma lida na documentação como fazer isto para esta biblioteca especificamente. E se é possível, embora quase certo que é. A licença permite fazer assim.

Normalmente basta usar a diretiva `-static` mas não garanto. Você precisará ter a `curlpp.a`.

Só me preocupa se o autor sabe o que está fazendo. Ele diz

> I don't have any licence of VC++ and I don't want to buy one"

Não é necessário comprar licença alguma para ter um compilador da Microsoft. Na verdade não só o compilador é grátis quase desde sempre, mas o Visual Studio simplificado também. E já faz um tempinho que o VS quase completo (antigo Professional) também é gratuito.

[Documentação da libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) onde explica o que fazer para compilar estaticamente.

Comment: Obrigado! Optei por distribuir a biblioteca (libcurlpp.so.0) juntamente com o programa e explicar como proceder no README